# Fetch data row by row with Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I want to fetch data from my mySQL db row by row so that I can combine the first column with the second and so on in a list.

I've searched and found solutions but none of them are using PDO.

Here's the php code that I'm using now to give me the first value written to the console with AJAX.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=XXXXX;dbname=XXXXX;charset=utf8', 'XXXXX', 
'XXXXX');
$partyID = ($_POST['paramName']);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wapp_Wishes_db WHERE partyID = '$partyID'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows[0]);
```

I've also tried using Fetch_assoc, but as you can see I'm probably using it completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you like to combine those rows? Encode them and use the variables in javascript:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
                      FROM wapp_Wishes_db 
                      WHERE partyID = :partyId");
$stmt->bindParam(':partyId', $_POST['paramName'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just want to write each row as a list item, users are able to add rows.

Comment: you can loop through `$rows` and print the values.. I really don't understand which is your desired result

Comment: Ok, I'll try to explain it:I've got x numbers of rows. I want each row to be printed in a <li> element.

Comment: I solved it with your first solution, you understood it correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `implode` like that :

```
$result = implode('&',$rows);
echo json_encode($result);
```

replace '&' by what you want.

More info here [on php manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php)